# Object Calling Errors

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am having some issues with my, spouse to be simple, proof of concept. I have established the arrays and put values inside of them. I also have a scanner intended to ask the user what index position they would like to change. However, when I goto run it gives me errors. I have reread the online tutorials and still am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated,
Liam

The errors are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Scanner to int
    The method toViewOrNotToView() is undefined for the type ObjectArrayDriver

    at ObjectArrayDriver.main(ObjectArrayDriver.java:85)
```

1st Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class A_of_Objects{
     private String digital; 
     private int cases;
     private String name;
     
     public A_of_Objects(){
         
     }
     
     public void setDigitalOrNot (String newDigital){
         digital = newDigital;
     }
     public void setCovidCases (int newCases){
         cases = newCases;
     }
     public void setSchool (String newName){
         name = newName;
     }
     
     public String getDigitalOrNot (){
         return digital;
     }
     public int getCovidCases (){
         return cases;
     }
     public String getSchool (){
         return name;
     }
     
     public void setupMethod(){
         System.out.println("This program tracks 10 schools in Greenville County (Private and Public)");
         System.out.println("It will allow an administrator to view and modify each's schools data");
         System.out.println("This data is for demonstration and is NOT accuate");
     }

     public String toString(){
         String report = "###################REPORT#####################\n";
         report += "School Name: " + name;
         report += "\nCovid-19 Cases: " + cases;
         report += "\nDigital or In Person? " + digital;
         
         return report;
     }
     
     public void toViewOrNotToView(){
         
         Scanner scanner1  = new Scanner(System.in);
         String modify = "modify";
         String view = "view";
         System.out.println("Would you like to view the data or modify it?");
         System.out.println("Type in \"view\" or \"modify\"");
            String askerAsk = scanner1.nextLine();
            if(askerAsk.equals(modify)){  
                System.out.println("You have chosen to modify the data.");
                System.out.println("What is the corresponding index # of the");
                System.out.print("school you would like to modify? 0-9");
                Scanner whatIndex = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println(testOA[0]);
                System.out.println("What item would you like to change?");
                System.out.println("0 for school name, 1 for cases, and 2 for digital or in person");
                Scanner whatItem = new Scanner(System.in);  
                
                                
            }
            if(askerAsk.equals(view)){ 
            System.out.println("You have chosen to view this data.");
            System.out.println("What is the corresponding index # of");
            System.out.print("school you would like to view? 0-9");
            Scanner whatIndex2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(testOA[whatIndex2]); //where the code stops working
            }
            

     }
    
}
```

**Driver class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ObjectArrayDriver {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        
    //  toViewOrNotToView();
        
        A_of_Objects[] testOA = new  A_of_Objects[10];
         
         testOA[0] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[1] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[2] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[3] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[4] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[5] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[6] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[7] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[8] = new  A_of_Objects();
         testOA[9] = new  A_of_Objects();
//#############################################0#######################################################
         testOA[0].setSchool("CCES");
         testOA[0].setCovidCases(20);
         testOA[0].setDigitalOrNot ("In Person");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[0]);
//#############################################1######################################################
         testOA[1].setSchool("JL Mann");
         testOA[1].setCovidCases(26);
         testOA[1].setDigitalOrNot ("In Person");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[1]);
//##############################################2####################################################
         testOA[2].setSchool("Saint Joes");
         testOA[2].setCovidCases(16);
         testOA[2].setDigitalOrNot ("Hybrid");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[2]);
//###############################################3###################################################
         testOA[3].setSchool("Stone Academy");
         testOA[3].setCovidCases(26);
         testOA[3].setDigitalOrNot ("Digital");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[3]);
//###############################################4##################################################
         testOA[4].setSchool("GTCHS");
         testOA[4].setCovidCases(22);
         testOA[4].setDigitalOrNot ("Hybrid");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[4]);
//######################################s#########5##################################################
         testOA[5].setSchool("Sara Collins Elementary");
         testOA[5].setCovidCases(3);
         testOA[5].setDigitalOrNot ("Digital");
        
         System.out.println(testOA[5]);
//###############################################6###################################################
         testOA[6].setSchool("AJ Whittenberg");
         testOA[6].setCovidCases(5);
         testOA[6].setDigitalOrNot ("Digital");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[6]);
//###############################################7###################################################
         testOA[7].setSchool("Southside Highschool");
         testOA[7].setCovidCases(10);
         testOA[7].setDigitalOrNot ("In Person");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[7]);
//###############################################8###################################################
         testOA[8].setSchool("Camperdown Academy");
         testOA[8].setCovidCases(15);
         testOA[8].setDigitalOrNot ("In Person");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[8]);
//################################################9##################################################
         testOA[9].setSchool("Leauge Academy");
         testOA[9].setCovidCases(25);
         testOA[9].setDigitalOrNot ("Hybrid");
         
         System.out.println(testOA[9]); 
         
         
        System.out.println("What is the corresponding index # of");
        System.out.print("school you would like to view? 0-9");
        Scanner whatIndex2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(testOA[whatIndex2]);
        
        toViewOrNotToView();
     }
    
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Sorry about that, the errors are:                                                                     
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Scanner to int
 The method toViewOrNotToView() is undefined for the type ObjectArrayDriver

 at ObjectArrayDriver.main(ObjectArrayDriver.java:85)

Comment: `System.out.println(testOA[whatIndex2])`. You need to pass an `int` to `[...]` but you pass a `Scanner`. Are you sure you didn't mean to get the index from the `Scanner` and then use that index?

Comment: `The method toViewOrNotToView() is undefined for the type ObjectArrayDriver` – That's true, the method  does not exist in `ObjectArrayDriver`. It does exist in `A_of_Object` though. Perhaps you meant to create an instance of `A_of_Object` and call the `toViewOrNotToView` method on that instance?